# Integrate $ \int \frac{(\sin x + \cos x \cdot e^{x+1})dx}{e^{x+1}\cdot \sin x}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrate $$\int \frac{(\sin x + \cos x \cdot e^{x+1})dx}{e^{x+1}\cdot \sin x}$$

I know I need to put $u$ instead of something, but I really tried everything and I still can't get the right solution. So I just need some suggestions. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Divide each term in the numerator by the term in the denumerator to simplify the integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you break up the numerator, you get $$\int e^{-x -1} dx + \int \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} d x.$$ Both these are easy.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int \dfrac{\left(\sin x + \cos x \cdot e^{x+1}\right)dx}{e^{x+1}\cdot \sin x}=\int{\dfrac{dx}{e^{x+1}}+\int{\dfrac{\cos{x}\ dx}{\sin{x}}}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Dividing out things simplifies it to two integrals:

$$I = \int e^{-(x+1)}dx + \int (\cot x) dx.$$